# Insert in teradata table very slow

Tags: sql, performance, teradata

I'm trying to insert 1,5 billion of lines into a table that already contains ~3 billions of lines. The problem is that this table is now very slow because of the huge amount of lines. Even a simple select if very very long. I'm new in Teradata (vantage) and I didnt create the table but I think that there are some possible optimizations.

It's a fact table, so only "insert" is uses, no update.

Here is the ddl (I renamed the table / column names):

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE MY_TABLE ,FALLBACK ,
 NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
 NO AFTER JOURNAL,
 CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
 DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO,
 MAP = TD_MAP1
 (
  SK_ID BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
       (START WITH 1 
        INCREMENT BY 1 
        MINVALUE -999999999999999999 
        MAXVALUE 999999999999999999 
        NO CYCLE),
  col1 VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
  col2 VARCHAR(15) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
  col3 TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
  col4 TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
  col5 VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
  col6 TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
  col7 DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd' NOT NULL,
  col8 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  col9 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  col10 BIGINT NOT NULL,
  col11 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  col12 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  col13 BIGINT NOT NULL,
  col14 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  col15 DECIMAL(16,4) NOT NULL,
  col16 DECIMAL(16,4) NOT NULL,
  col17 VARCHAR(4) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
  col18 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  col19 DECIMAL(16,4) NOT NULL,
  col20 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  col21 DECIMAL(16,4) NOT NULL,
  col22 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  col23 DECIMAL(16,4) NOT NULL,
  col24 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  col25 DECIMAL(16,4) NOT NULL,
  col26 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  col27 DECIMAL(16,4) NOT NULL,
  col28 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  col29 DECIMAL(16,4) NOT NULL,
  col30 VARCHAR(1) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
  col31 VARCHAR(1) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
  col32 INTEGER,
  col34 INTEGER,
  col35 VARCHAR(6) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
  col36 VARCHAR(6) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
  col37 BIGINT NOT NULL,
  col38 VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
  col39 VARCHAR(1) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
  col40 CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
  col41 DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  col42 DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  col43 DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd');
 UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX (SK_ID)
```

As you can see there is A PI on the auto increment column, is it really usefull ? Because obviously this column will never be used in a "join" or where" clause. I checked and there is no other uniq column in the whole table.

Do you see any possible optimizations to make this big tables healthier ?

Thank you for your help,

Regards,

Thomas

Comment: first the min vlaue makes no sense, as you start with 1, so how can it get negatove, and for joining it it helpful to have indexes and also a useful primary key. Also keep normalisation i mind when designing a databse

Comment: To optimize you need knowledge how this table is accessed. A PI should be mainly based on access, join and where. Look at the Foreign Keys used for join and check if they're not too skewed. For a 3 billion row table partitioning might be usefull, maybe based on a date/timestamp matching the load.

Comment: Primary index need not be unique. For a fact table, generally the PI is some subset of the dimension columns (maybe starting with those that have the largest number of distinct values). As far as INSERTs, you'd be better off with a NO PRIMARY INDEX table than this. And in principle when you are inserting such a large number of rows relative to the current table size, it's more efficient to load the new rows to a work table and then merge (UNION ALL) the two into a new table, but the GENERATED ALWAYS column makes that approach impractical.

Comment: If the identity column isn't used in joins or where clauses, then not only is it a poor choice for a PI, I would question why it's even there.  Based on what you're saying, it's completely meaningless